# How to get realm roles with user data in keycloak Admin API

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services

API: POST /{realm}/users

According to documentation they specify that realm roles are there but its not added to user data when API is called.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you mean `GET`, not `POST`? But that doesn't matter.

Indeed the returned `UserRepresentation`-s contain only a subset of all of the [documented properties](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) and the realm roles are not part of this subset. The documentation is silent on this "small" detail and it seems to be a source of confusion. You may look [here](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-August/007233.html).

You can use `auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings/realm` to get the roles. For example:

```
  curl \
    -H "Authorization: bearer ...." \
    "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/<realm-here>/users/<user-id-here>/role-mappings/realm"
```

Response:

```
[
   {
      "id":"dcc58028-ba8a-4545-bafe-e8004488e4c5",
      "name":"admin",
      "description":"${role_admin}",
      "composite":true,
      "clientRole":false,
      "containerId":"master"
   },
   {
      "id":"99f5bb44-c203-493f-9eaa-6ec3a8ff264a",
      "name":"uma_authorization",
      "description":"${role_uma_authorization}",
      "composite":false,
      "clientRole":false,
      "containerId":"master"
   },
   {
      "id":"51853542-2ee8-4b29-b05c-03ef86f5b333",
      "name":"offline_access",
      "description":"${role_offline-access}",
      "composite":false,
      "clientRole":false,
      "containerId":"master"
   }
]
```